# How to remove append image using jquery

Tags: jquery, image

```
a(document).on("click.frTTS", "#fr_screenreader_play,#allmode-id126,.allmode-text,.allmode-topitem,.itemFullText,#k2Container" ,function(b) {
    var abc = $(this).attr('id');
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
    if(abc == "fr_screenreader_play")
    {     $('<img src="http://www.test.com/arc/eng/images/speaker32.png">').remove();
    }    else
    {
        $(this).append('<img src="http://www.test.com/arc/eng/images/speaker32.png">');
    }
    c = true;
    d = "play";
    clearTimeout(e);
    f = w();
    if (!f.length) z("notext"); else {
        t();
        if ("proxy_responsive" == l.readerEngine) responsiveVoice.speak(f, j, {
            volume: l.screenReaderVolume / 100,
            onend: function() {
                z("finished");
                alert("finished");
                $('<img src="http://www.test.com/arc/eng/images/speaker32.png">').remove();
            }
        }); else q();
        z("playing");
    }
    a("#fr_screenreader_pause").removeClass("active");
    b.stopPropagation();
    b.preventDefault();
});
```

I want to remove the image after loop finishes. After getting alert closed. Please help me to fix this issue. I am trying to fix this issue from morning. It is my first Javascript modification.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see where is the loop...
And I don't know where is the `setTimeout` that you're clearing.

But anyway, your question is about how to remove a particular image based on its url.

So, instead of:

```
$('<img src="http://www.test.com/arc/eng/images/speaker32.png">').remove();
```

Use this:

```
$('img[src="http://www.test.com/arc/eng/images/speaker32.png"]').remove();
```

Or this shortest, which can be useful.
Notice the `*`.
It checks if the attribute *contains* something:

```
$('img[src*="speaker32.png"]').remove();
```

It looks like a pretty subtile syntax change...
But it is important.
Because you can not just use an element as you would define it in HTML for a jQuery selector.
Here, the selector is any `img` tag that has an attribute `src` containing the specific url...

;)